# Laravel using MPDF in a Docker container can't find my image urls (due to docker)

Tags: php, docker, laravel-5, docker-compose

#### Issue: Any URL put in creating a PDF, MPDF can't find it (throws an Exception).

`Exception: cURL error: \"Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 8000: Connection refused\"`

I have both web and API in this app, and strangely, my web app HTML can find those images. I have created a pretty basic environment following the tutorials.

I'm using `http://127.0.0.1:8000/` as base URL to access for my app and API.

- Images is located at `ROOT_DIR/public/uploads/report_templates/logo/logo-white.png`
- Web can see this via `http://127.0.0.1:8000/uploads/report_templates/logo/logo-white.png`.

#### Things I found

- Any external URL like `https://www.google.pl/images/srpr/logo11w.png` can be found.
- If I place absolute path instead of URL it is found (can't resort to this tough since this a lengthy report.)
- using `curl` from inside the container for `http://127.0.0.1:8000/uploads/report_templates/logo/logo-white.png` says `Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 8000: Connection refused`

I understand, I'm doing it wrong in the 3rd point requesting into my own container. But can't find anything specific in web & too new to docker to think of something my own.

I'm looking for a proper way to handle this in docker.

#### .env

```
   ...
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
APP_URL=http://127.0.0.1:8000/
   ...
```

#### docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  app:
    build:
      args:
        user: daniyalnasir
        uid: 1001
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: f-scope
    container_name: f-scope-app
    restart: unless-stopped
    working_dir: /var/www/
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
    networks:
      f-scope:


  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    container_name: f-scope-db
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ${DB_DATABASE}
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
#      MYSQL_USER: ${DB_USERNAME}
#      MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 1
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
      SERVICE_NAME: mysql
    volumes:
      - dbdata1:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./docker-compose/mysql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    networks:
      f-scope:
        ipv4_address: 172.24.2.1
  nginx:
    image: nginx:alpine
    container_name: f-scope-nginx
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - 8000:80
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
      - ./public/uploads:/var/www/public/uploads
      - ./docker-compose/nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
    networks:
      f-scope:


networks:
  f-scope:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - subnet: "172.24.2.0/16"

volumes:
  dbdata1:
```

#### Dockerfile

```
FROM php:7.4-fpm

# Arguments defined in docker-compose.yml
ARG user
ARG uid

# Install system dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    git \
    curl \
    libpng-dev \
    libonig-dev \
    libxml2-dev \
    libgd-dev \
    libzip-dev \
    zip \
    sendmail \
    unzip

# Clear cache
RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Install PHP extensions
RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd --enable-gd --with-freetype --with-jpeg
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql mbstring exif pcntl bcmath gd zip


# Configure sendmail path
RUN echo "sendmail_path=/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/sendmail.ini

#RUN sed -i '/#!\/bin\/sh/aservice sendmail restart' /usr/local/bin/docker-php-entrypoint
#RUN sed -i '/#!\/bin\/sh/aecho "$(hostname -i)\t$(hostname) $(hostname).localhost" >> /etc/hosts' /usr/local/bin/docker-php-entrypoint

# Get latest Composer
COPY --from=composer:latest /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer

# Create system user to run Composer and Artisan Commands
RUN useradd -G www-data,root -u $uid -d /home/$user $user
RUN mkdir -p /home/$user/.composer && \
    chown -R $user:$user /home/$user

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /var/www

USER $user
```

#### HTML

```
<img src="{{url("uploads/report_templates/logo/logo-white.png")}}" style="width: 250px; height:80px; margin: 70px 0px 40px 30px;" alt="" />
```

---

#### For context

I'm using **MPDF** to create a PDF that has images URLs (*pointing to my application's public folders*). It works fine on my regular LAMP environment.

But, to learn I decided to create & run this app in docker container on my local machine *(running ubuntu)*. Everything is working as it should in this docker environment, except for this one thing.

Answer (score 0):

When utilizing Docker in development environments, it's crucial to appropriately configure the `basepath` used for relative src and href attributes to ensure accessibility. In the context you provided, Mpdf is attempting to access an image via `http://yourapp.test:8000/uploads/report_templates/logo/logo-white.png`, yet the nginx container fails to resolve the host (`yourapp.test`) and establish a connection on port 8000.

Therefore, the `basepath` should be configured as either "localhost", "127.0.0.1", or the local IP address of the container.

```php
$mpdf = new Mpdf();
$mpdf->SetBasePath('http://localhost');
```

In cases where the nginx container operates on a port other than 80, it's necessary to specify the port:

```php
// For instance, if the nginx container runs on port 8080.
$mpdf->SetBasePath('http://localhost:8080');
```

However, it's important to note that this configuration ideally shouldn't be required in production since `basepath` should be appropriately configured and accessible.